# What is the syntax to trigger searchbox 'places_changed' event programmatically via angular-google-maps?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I need to trigger the `places_changed` event of angular-google-maps searchbox programmatically, instead of manually pressing enter. How do I accomplish this?

I tried using the vanilla js solution :

```
google.maps.event.trigger(searchbox, 'places_changed');
```

But I am unsure of what to send as the first parameter.

This is my markup :

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' draggable="true" options="map.options" control="map.control">
    <ui-gmap-search-box template="searchbox.template" events="searchbox.events" position="'TOP_LEFT'">
    </ui-gmap-search-box>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

This is my controller code :

$scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 45,
                longitude: -73
            },
            zoom: 8
        };
        $scope.map.control = {};
        $scope.map.options = {
            scrollwheel: true
        };

```
    var events = {
        places_changed: function(searchBox) {
            console.log("Search Box :", searchBox.getPlaces());
            var location = searchBox.getPlaces();
            console.log("Location :", location[0].geometry.location["G"]);
            var geoKeys = Object.keys(location[0].geometry.location);
            console.log("Keys :", geoKeys);
            $scope.map["center"]["latitude"] = location[0]["geometry"]["location"][geoKeys[0]];
            $scope.map["center"]["longitude"] = location[0]["geometry"]["location"][geoKeys[1]];
            uiGmapIsReady.promise(1).then(function(maps) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    console.log("Map :", $scope.map.control.getGMap());
                    console.log("Bounds :", $scope.map.control.getGMap().getBounds());
                    if (location[0].geometry.viewport) {
                        $scope.map.control.getGMap().fitBounds(location[0].geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        $scope.map["zoom"] = 15;
                    }
                    var marker = [{
                        coordinates: {
                            latitude: $scope.map["center"]["latitude"],
                            longitude: $scope.map["center"]["longitude"]
                        },
                        title: location[0]["name"],
                        id: location[0]["id"],
                        icon: location[0]["icon"]
                    }];
                    $scope.randomMarkers = marker;
                    console.log("Random Markers :", $scope.randomMarkers);
                });
                console.info("Google Maps ready", $scope.map);

            });
            //$scope.map.fitBounds(location[0].geometry.viewport);
        }
    }

    $scope.searchbox = {
        template: 'app/user/editProfile/map-search.html',
        events: events
    };
```

Now I need to trigger the "places_changed" event by an `ng-click` from somewhere else in the page. How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to trigger the enter key event on the searchBox and it will produce the same results.
Edit 1 - google.maps.event.trigger is available AFTER the google API has been loaded via angular.
This is how I have it in my own app:

```
uiGmapIsReady.promise(1).then(function(instances) {
        instances.forEach(function(inst) {
            // run the searchbox with the input provided
            $timeout(function() {
                var input = angular.element("#" + 'id_of_searchBox')[0];
                google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'focus')
                google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
                    keyCode: 13
                });
            }, 100);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Since I am using angular-google-maps service wraparound instead of directly using the google apis I am unable to access google.maps.event object.

Comment: You are unable to access the google.maps.event object because of a race condition. The google object is loaded even if you are using the angular-google-maps directive. I edited the code above to return a promise when the google map is ready. You need to inject uiGmapIsReady into your controller for it to work.